# What does the $\times$ in the context of multilinear forms in linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, notation, linear-transformations

I frequently see notation similar to $B: V \times V \to K$ in the context of linear algebra, where we now have the $\times$ symbol and more than one vector space. I realise that this is used to represent a linear transformation in [*multilinear* algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_form) (the aforementioned notation is a bilinear form). However, my only understanding of the $\times$ symbol/operator is as the cross/Cartesian product, so I have been unable to understand what the presence of the $\times$ means in this context.

My immediate interpretation is that $B: V \times V \to K$ denotes a linear transformation $B$ that maps from a vector space which is the cross product of $V$ with itself to another vector space, $K$. However, I don't even understand what the cross product of two vector spaces *means*.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to explain what this notation actually *means*. My studies until now have focused on what would likely be considered elementary linear algebra, so I would appreciate an explanation that is targeted towards this level of knowledge.

EDIT: I have also seen the notation $\mathbf{R}^n \times \mathbf{R}^n$ (specifically, second order tensors $\in \mathbf{R}^n \times \mathbf{R}^n$), so I would also appreciate an explanation of what this means.

Comment: It is the Cartesian product of sets.

Answer (score 5):

Functions always have exactly one argument. When we want to express that a function $f$ takes $k$ arguments, the common convention is therefore to let $f$ have $k$-tuples as arguments, and this is where Cartesian products are used.

$V \times V$ is the Cartesian product of $V$ with itself, that is,

$$V \times V = \{ (v_1,v_2) \mid v_1 \in V, v_2 \in V \}$$

A bilinear form $B: V \times V \rightarrow K$ (where $K$ denotes the field of scalars) takes two vectors and returns a value from $K$ – and is linear in each of its arguments.